# How are bounty questions migrated from SE 1.0 to SE 2.0?

Tags: discussion, migration, stackexchange-2.0

Stumbled across this question:  [What is the difference between "good debt" vs. "bad debt"?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/774/what-is-the-difference-between-good-debt-vs-bad-debt) which was migrated from the SE 1.0 basicallymoney.com site.

I believe it was a bounty based on the text "Note: This question is a Bounty FAQ. More info here."

Is there a strategy for migrating bounty questions?  Is that information lost in the migration?  If so, I think we should plan to scour the seeded questions to remove traces of "bounty".